# Want to set custom domain to my heroku app for godaddy domain name

Tags: heroku, dns

I registered a naked domain name "passonate.com". I want set this domain to my app which is hosted on heroku. But I am not able to do it. Can you please provide solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains:

```
$ heroku domains:add example.com 
Adding example.com to example... done
```